# OpenAI Dalle Node createImageEdit 400 Error

Tags: node.js, api, openai-api

I am trying to use the OpenAI package in Node to send an edit request as follows:

```
let response = await openai.createImageEdit(
  fs.createReadStream('assets/cute_cat.png'),
  fs.createReadStream('assets/mask.png'),
  'a cat with a hat',
  1,
  '512x512'
);
```

```
statusCode: 400,

statusMessage: 'Bad Request',
```

However, upon getting the response I always get a vague 400 error and cannot find anything online. I tried sending it with an Axios request to no avail. I also managed to have the same set of images work in Python with the Python package but for some reason in Node it keeps throwing an error. The images are square and within the size constraints of the API, I believe the arguments are correctly formatted too.

Any help or ideas is highly appreciated everyone. Thanks!

Comment: Axios + FormData, it needs to be a multipart

Answer (score 0):

Check out this issue: https://github.com/openai/openai-node/issues/95

The documentation is incorrect regarding the order of parameters for createImageEdit. The order should be: image, prompt, mask.

Change it to this and it should work:

```
let response = await openai.createImageEdit(
  fs.createReadStream('assets/cute_cat.png'),
  'a cat with a hat',
  fs.createReadStream('assets/mask.png'),
  1,
  '512x512'
);
```